# Delete folder but exclude specific folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

For student computers I need to cleanup the windows `userprofile-folders` in (C:\Users*). But I need to keep the following folder (and do it with batch, no powershell-scripts possible, only single commands):

- Administrator
- All Users
- Default
- Default.lic
- Default User
- defaultuser0
- Public
- 40040
- 40041

I tried this one, but it deleted all folder and didn't exclude anything:

```
if "%1" == "Administrator" goto End
if "%1" == "All Users" goto End
if "%1" == "Default" goto Ende
if "%1" == "Default.lic" goto End
if "%1" == "Default User" goto End
if "%1" == "defaultuser0" goto End
if "%1" == "Public" goto End
if "%1" == "40040" goto End
if "%1" == "40041" goto End
rmdir /S /Q "C:\Users\%1"
powershell "Remove-Item -Path \"HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\S-1-5-21-21*\" -Recurse"
:End
```

In my mind is the idea to do with something like an `excludelist`, but `findstr` didn't work out. The examples I found where all using only one variable etc. but is this case it should be something in the way:

```
if C:\Users\* is not C:\Users\*excluded-folder-variable* do rmdir /S /Q "C:\Users\%1"
```

Comment: What value does `%1` (which should be `%~1`) contain?

Comment: In a batch file could be used the single command line: `@for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir C:\Users\* /AD-L /B ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /V /X /C:Administrator /C:"All Users" /C:Default /C:Default.lic /C:"Default User" /C:defaultuser0 /C:Public /C:40040 /C:40041') do @rd /Q /S "C:\Users\%%I"`

Comment: `for /D %%J in ("%SystemDrive%\Users\*") do set "FLAG=#" & (for %%I in ("Administrator" "All Users" "Default" "Default.lic" "Default User" "defaultuser0" "Public" "40040" "40041") do if /I "%%~nxJ"=="%%~I" set "FLAG=") & if defined FLAG rd /S /Q "%%~J"`…

Comment: You can insert the exclude list in a file, one name per line, and use `findstr "%~1" excludeList.txt > NUL` followed by `if not errorlevel 1 rmdir ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "exclude=|Administrator|All Users|Default|Default.lic|Default User|defaultuser0|Public|40040|40041|"

cd "C:\Users"

for /D %%f in (*) do (
   if "!exclude:|%%~f|=!" equ "%exclude%" rmdir /S /Q "%%~f"
)
```

You have not shown where your `%1` comes from, but you may insert the `if "!exclude:...` command in your code changing `%%~f` by `%~1` and adjusting subdirectory as needed...

Answer (score 0):

If all the folders to exclude are in the `Users` folder, it's easiest to use the following code:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%d in ('dir /b /ad "%HOMEDRIVE%\Users"') do call :REMOVE "%%d"
goto :EOF
:REMOVE
if /i "%~1" == "Administrator" goto :EOF
if /i "%~1" == "All Users" goto :EOF
if /i "%~1" == "Default" goto :EOF
if /i "%~1" == "Default.lic" goto :EOF
if /i "%~1" == "Default User" goto :EOF
if /i "%~1" == "defaulters0" goto :EOF
if /i "%~1" == "Public" goto :EOF
if /i "%~1" == "40040" goto :EOF
if /i "%~1" == "40041" goto :EOF
rd /s /q "%~1"
```

You can add or remove any folder you want in the same way.